# How to type through the keyboard programmatically in android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

When user click on the field and keyboard comes up, by pressing the `Enter/Go` key, I want to type my own value into the field, instead of system keyboard.
I want to do this in background of my app, and fill the fields of other apps.

Is it possible job, or I'm a greedy man?! :)

Answer (score 0):

> Yes it is possible, you are not greedy :P

You can add `onKeyListener()` on each of your `EditText` fields. It will listen to each key stroke by you user and as soon user press `Enter`, you can perform your required logic.

```
final EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);

edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button

        if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
            (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {

          Toast.makeText(MyExampleActivity.this, "enter is pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          return true;

        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Actually I want to do this in background (using `AccessibilityService`), not in an `activity`, and I don't have `EditText` instance, just `AccessibilityNodeInfo`!